# Как поменять раскладку в режиме восстановления ubuntu 18.04

Tags: ubuntu, grub, root, sudo

Нужно добавить пользователя в группу sudo. Выполняю всё как [здесь](https://www.tecmint.com/fix-user-is-not-in-the-sudoers-file-the-incident-will-be-reported-ubuntu/) написано.
 В режиме восстановления в консоли требуется набрать команду 
"mount -o rw,remount /"
Но я пишу на русском, никак не удаётся перейти на английский язык. Можете подсказать, как это сделать?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Пробовал комбинации 
`ctrl + shift` и `alt + shift`

Comment: ctrl+shift? Или напишите, какие комбинации не работают.

Comment: У меня такая же ситуация. Подскажите нашли ли какой нибудь выход?

Comment: Войдите в систему через обычный или безопасный режим и сделайте английскую раскладку первой в списке.